# classic experience vs modern experience, getting the right link

Tags: modern-experience, classic-experience

When in classic experience via the dots, it is very easy to get the exact url of the document (I mean something that ends in `....abc.docx`).

When using the modern experience I am unable to get the same, since the 'get a link' is always asking you for 'people' to share with and produces a different result link.

Is there a way to get the proper link via the modern experience?

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

Currently there is not direct way provided by Microsoft to get the proper link of document in modern experience.

**Work Around**:

You can use **Export to Excel** option in modern SharePoint Library which exports all the information in document library along with the clean URL of your documents.

[image]

Comment: Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

They were changed the sharing options in new look with the sharing functions, so there is no more the ...abc.docx link, you are using link which defining permission on document and automatically openning in Online Office.

If user need to get document proper, just click on the menu in left top corner:
[image]

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: in your case smernice is the library, not the file. In my case it is the library

Comment: yes you will get to the file this way, you are not able to get link ...abc.docx as i said in new look