# SPO - Get file by URL (generated by "Get Link")

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, links

Is it possible to get document from SharePoint Online document library by link URL, that is generated from UI with "Get link" functionality in PowerShell?
[image]

Link example: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/EcsPC4X-lvtGp-c_5QOee_cJSccfFS0aFvdPLxIr19MMPQ`

Comment: You can get bit cleaner link to the document, see my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258041/classic-experience-vs-modern-experience-getting-the-right-link/258051).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently found the solution by myself (partly using PnP) - function `GetFileByUrl` does the job.

```
cls

$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline –Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" –Credentials $credential

$ctx = Get-PnPContext  

$web = Get-PnPWeb 
Write-Host "Web: " $web.Url

$item = $web.GetFileByUrl("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/EcsPC4X-lvtGp-c_5QOee_cJSccfFS0aFvdPLxIr19MMPQ")
$ctx.Load($item)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-Host "Item:" $item.Name

$ctx = $null

Write-Host "End" -f Green -b DarkGreen
Write-host " "
Write-host " "
```