# Copying the “normal” (classic) link of an item in SharePoint Online (New Experience)

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, spfx-extensions, new-experience

I want to copy the old school classic link from a document which looks like http://team./sites/sitename/libraryname/imagename.PNG .

However, Sharepoint online generates a link like "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/EcBgGUOtGLZAnWAxNhPEAl4BYd_hDxjbWMKuO0U1XZqwxw?e=aTcmoD" which is not human readable. Can I get the classic link in Sharepoint Online?

There is a [blog post](https://medium.com/@anoopt/copying-the-normal-classic-link-of-an-item-in-sharepoint-8baaf779e924) that provides an "SPFx extension" as a solution but I was wondering if we could find a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

Currently there is not direct way provided by Microsoft to get the proper link of document in modern experience.

**Work Around**:

Follow below steps(It will give you quite readable link):

`Select the file in library > Copy link > Click the drop down button below link and Choose “Specific people” > Apply(Without Entering anyone's name) > Copy the link.`

**Reference**:

1. [classic experience vs modern experience, getting the right link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258041/classic-experience-vs-modern-experience-getting-the-right-link/258051)

Comment: I cannot click apply without entering anyone's name. There is validation applied on "Enter a name or email" text box.

Comment: I am able to get the link without adding anyone's name. If you are not getting it then try adding your own name. But I guess adding your name will not give you the more readable link.

Comment: Does this answer helped you in any way to get the solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't able to do it. Perhaps it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Another place where you can get a usable link is in the version history for the file

Comment: Thanks this helped me Kasper!