# Get link to file without sharing the file

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, url, file

Me and a colleague both have access to the same document library. I want to tell him to take a look at a PDF file inside this library. When I click on "Copy Link" a link is created and an additional entry in "Has Access" is created: "1 link giving access".

I do not want to create an additional permission - I just need a link to a file me and my colleague both have access to.

Can I just copy the URL from the Browser?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can get the link of document file from Library.

If you are going to share just the URL of file (assuming access is already has been given) to your colleague then you can open the file and copy the URL from browser.

That should work.

---

You can file URL/link by following this as well:

1. Go to document library/folder where your file is uploaded.
2. Select the file and click on **Open the details pane** (`i` icon) from command bar (top right side).
3. **Copy direct link** using the copy icon highlighted in below image:

[image]

**Reference**: [Uploading files in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305662/uploading-files-in-sharepoint/305663#305663)

Comment: Can you further elaborate on 'multiple ways' to get a  link. What else can I do to get a link?

Comment: First and easiest way is to copy link from browser. second you can create link if you know the site url, document library and file name like `siteUrl/document library/filename.extension`. another way to get the clean link to your document is using Export to Excel option, check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258041/classic-experience-vs-modern-experience-getting-the-right-link/258051#258051).

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP - when should I share link and when should I add direct access?

Comment: Share direct file link when user already has access to the files. If user don't have access to file, provide access first and then share the file URL/link.

Answer (score 1):

Got your question.

Getting the link is a bit tricky, especially if you have Modern settings enabled for your library.

What you can do is just open the document in the browser and share the link directly with your colleague.

Your colleague can then access this document .

Make sure your colleague has read access on this file , so that he can open it too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you are sure your colleague has access to this file, you can simple copy and share the URL from the browser.
As mentioned in your question, the 'Copy Link' and other sharing options creates a new sharing link (and also unique permissions) on the file.

You could also use - 'People with existing access' in the Link Settings, which will not make a new entry in the Has Access section.

I have recently blogged more details on this, you can refer it here - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-sharepoint-online-file-sharing-and-when-unique-permissions-are-cre/

Comment: When I choose 'People with existing access' it still creates a link permission

Comment: Thanks! @Kiril I tried this just now and found that if we set the default sharing settings on the site level to default new links to only share with people with existing access, then the right-click -> copy link feature does not generate a new sharing link and does not break inheritance/add explicit permissions on the item.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to bother with a sharing link. The easiest way shall be opening the file and copy the URL in the browser. The copy link action gives you sharing link is a by-design behavior.