# Uploading files in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, administration, document, file

Whether all the files in SharePoint are in same folder or in those folders we determine?

How to get the path of the file from SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Files will be stored where you add/upload those files.

1. You can store all files inside document library without any folders
2. You can create folders (also subfolders inside folder) and add files inside folders

Check below Microsoft documentations for more information:

1. [Create a folder in a document library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-folder-in-a-document-library-3d6a8c11-2490-4d6b-8837-f25649a69c56)
2. [Create, upload, and share files in a document library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-upload-and-share-files-in-a-document-library-98cb2ff2-c27e-42ea-b055-c2d895f8a5de)
3. [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59) - best practices to follow if you are going to upload more than 5000 files in same document library

---

You can check the path of file by following this:

1. Go to document library/folder where your file is uploaded
2. Select the file and click on **Open the details pane** (i icon) from command bar (top right side)
3. **Copy direct link** using the copy icon highlighted in below image:

[image]