# Image Map not showing on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, administration, html

I have built a HTML image map which works just fine while both the HTML file and the image are on my local Desktop (i.e. same directory).

Yet as soon as I upload both to the SharePoint document library (also same directory) and try to embed the image map, I am seeing an (almost) blank Embed Web Part (image below):

[image]

I would appreciate any support (I realize this might be an easy fix).

Thanks!

Comment: If you are referencing image URLs in HTML code, try using the image URL's from SharePoint library. You can get the image URL by following the steps given here (using **Copy direct link** option: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305662/uploading-files-in-sharepoint/305663#305663. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Ghanesh, that fixed it, thanks a ton!

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload the HTML files and images in same folder inside the SharePoint document library, it will not work similar to how it worked in your local desktop.

As you are referencing image URLs in HTML file code, you will have to use the relative image URL's from SharePoint document library itself.

You can get the image URLs by following the steps given here (using **Copy direct link** option): [Uploading files in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305662/uploading-files-in-sharepoint/305663#305663)

[image]