# How to include a link to a supporting document in "Start and wait for approval"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, flow, approval-process

I have created a document approval workflow in Power Automate for a SharePoint Library. This is working fine.

I now want to add a link to a supporting document which could be 5-20MB in size (from another folder in the same SharePoint Library) in the approval notification mail.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Markdown in Power automate approval actions to add rich formatting (hyperlinks, font formatting, etc.) to your approval requests.

Check the documentation: [Use Markdown language in Power Automate approval requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/approvals-markdown-support)

Follow these steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint document library and copy link to supporting document. Follow this thread for detailed steps: [Uploading files in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305662/uploading-files-in-sharepoint/305663#305663)

   [image]
2. Append `?Web=1` at the end of document URL if you want to open the document in browser else document will be downloaded on click of hyperlink.
3. Go to your Power automate flow & locate "Start and wait for approval" action.
4. Then you can add the hyperlink to supporting document in approval action using markdown like:

   [image]

Hyperlink format in markdown is like:

```
[Link Text](Link URL)
```

**Output (in Outlook web)**:

[image]