# 'Copy Link' and 'Share' create unique permission automatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, administration, document

I've done some investigating and if I use "Share" -> "People with existing access" it does not create unique permissions.

However, if the user clicks on "Copy Link", it automatically creates a link using our default ("People in our organization"), before I am able to change the setting to "People with existing access". This is what is creating all of the random unique permissions.

Do anyone know if there is a way to prevent a file from getting a unique permission if the users want to copy the link?

Comment: Copy file URL by following [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305662/uploading-files-in-sharepoint/305663#305663) instead of "Copy link" option. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to change the SharePoint default functionality of "Copy link" option in the document library.

If you want a direct link to SharePoint file to share with users who are already having permissions on the file, follow below steps to get the file URL:

1. Go to the document library/folder where your file is uploaded.
2. Select the file and click on **Open the details pane** (`i` icon) from command bar (top right side)
3. **Copy direct link** using the copy icon highlighted in below image:

[image]

You may need to append `?Web=1` to open file in web browser before sharing it with other users, like:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/MyLibrary/MyDocument.docx?Web=1
```

---

Additionally, you can hide the "Copy link" option from library command bar using SharePoint JSON view formatting:

```
{
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "copyLink",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```