# Embed file with path/name instead of unique ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, administration, iframe, embedded

I have a list of SharePoint documents that I want to embed in an iframe on an external website, but the end users find it too time consuming to give me the file unique IDs, so I only have their filenames.

SharePoint's Embed feature suggests an iframe with `embed.aspx?UniqueId=...` as a source. Can we pass other parameters than the file's unique ID, like its path and name? After some research I didn't find anything about it.

Comment: Try this: Get file URL by following the steps given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305662/uploading-files-in-sharepoint/305663#305663) using **Copy direct link** option and try using that URL for embedding. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap-MVP, unfortunately it doesn't work in an iframe on a different domain because it's not an `embed.aspx` link and thus gets blocked by the x-frame-options / content-security policy.